# how can i find the confidence level of svm using scikit-learn library

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

In image classification using svm I want to get the confidence level of the prediction of SVM. example: a picture with tiger. svm predicted that it is a tiger but for how much confidence level? or it can say it is a cat for what confidence level or reliability. By the way i am using bag of features

Comment: i will try the code to see if it satistfies my question thanks a lot maxymoo :)

Comment: by the way I am using nusvc() is that applicable to this function too : nusvc(probability=true) ??

Comment: from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf=SVC(probability=True)
clf.fit(X,Y)
print clf.predict_proba(W) #No error ---is this code applicable in testing which class an  image belongs to?